# How can I have the grouped variables in an SSRS report show up on each page, either on the footer or header of the page?

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services

I have a main report with several subreports, all within a tablix.  The report is grouped by an Investor Id value and the details for the Investor Id span multiple pages when its printed.  My issue is that I'm not able to display the investor id on each page, either on the footer or the header.  I just need it to show up for each page, I don't care if its on the bottom or the top.  Can this be done?

[image]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Assuming investor ID is available in your main report/dataset (I assume you are passing this to the sub-report) . Set page breaks on the row group in your main report (set as "between" ) then add a row to the top of the row group that groups by investor, then you can add you investor id field in this row.

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield.  I've got several subreports, which could make the report for the investor id - one to n # of pages.  Where would I put that row group to ensure that the investor id shows up on each page and changes as investor id changes.  I was reading up on your suggetion on =(reportitems!textbox.value, "groupID").  that seemed to be a good way to go but would I put that in an expression?  I get an error saying it doesn't like the format.   Thanks

Comment: If you edit your question and show the current design of the MAIN, including the rowgroup panel below the main design window, then I can guide you better. Make sure you select your tablix before you do the screenshot so that any grouping in the tablix will be visible. It's 11pm here now so I won't get back to you until sometime tomorrow.

Comment: @AlanSchofield.  Hi Alan.  was able to attach the image.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @AlanSchofield.  Please let me know if you need more images on the question.  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I posted an answer yesterday then realised it would not work so I deleted it. I'll have to setup a test report to replicate your scenario and see what I can do - if anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested this and it seems to work fine, and it's simple.

First, click your `ID` row group in the row group panel below the main designer and then hit F4 to get to the properties. In the properties window, expand the "Group" section and set the `PageName` property to whatever you want to show in your header (e.g. `="Investor ID = " & Fields!ID.Value`).

Next, set the PageBreak to `Between`

[image]

Now, in your header add a textbox and set the expression to be `=Globals!PageName`.

That's it, the pagename property will change for each value in the dataset in your main report and be applied to the header on each page.

Comment: Hi Alan.  This is what I exactly needed,  thank you for answering my question!  I hope this helps other people as well.

Comment: Glad I could help and I learned something new myself while I was experimenting... "Every day is a school day" (even when you're old like me)

Comment: Hi Alan,  do you ever do freelance work?

Comment: No really but you can find me on linkedin (although I don't really use it much) and let me know if you have any work/projects in mins and we can discuss outside stackoverflow.